# what are all the key names in keyboard module?

Tags: python

In the python keyboard module https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/ what are all the names of the keys? can anybody give me a list of it because I can't find one.

Comment: There's a link to API docs on the pypi page and it has all the keys listed.

Comment: @pavel: No it doesn't. It's got a list of functions, classes, and constants, but no complete list of keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`keyboard` doesn't have such a list in the docs, or even in the source code. `keyboard` builds its key information tables at runtime by querying key information [from Windows APIs](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/v0.13.5/keyboard/_winkeyboard.py#L383) or [from `dumpkeys`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/v0.13.5/keyboard/_nixkeyboard.py#L62), then applying a bit of its own postprocessing.

The key information tables `keyboard` builds aren't anywhere in its public API, but if you import `keyboard`, the private `keyboard._os_keyboard.from_name` table should have all of `keyboard`'s canonical key names. `keyboard._canonical_names.canonical_names` should have the mapping from non-canonical names to canonical names, if you want that info too, but I'm not sure everything in that table is actually guaranteed to be a supported key.